# Can't install apk on device with Android API 15 though minSdkVersion = 15

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I have a build.gradle file `minSdkVersion` set to 15 but I failed to install the apk on any version < 19 (I get a message `Application no installed`).

What could be wrong?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.+'
    compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.1.1@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0@jar'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.4.1@aar'
    compile files('libs/OoyalaSDK.jar')
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.2.1@jar'
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:2.0.1@aar'
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.3.4@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.+'
}
```

**EDIT**

I've just tried with a simple default project created in Android Studio and I get the same issue. I can debug the app, but if I create an apk and try to install it manually, I get the error `Application not installed` (the apk is signed and aligned).

Comment: Have you tried to compile with API 15? Maybe you are using api 19 where you couldn't.

Comment: I'm compiling on API 19 and it works perfectly. My issue is when I compile an apk I cannot install it on lower version.

Comment: You are probably using API 19 functionality which just won't work on an API 15 device ...

Comment: Wouldn't this give me any compilation error?

Comment: I set `compileSdkVersion` and `minSdkVersion` to 15, get no errors at compiling and it still cannot be installed on a device with Android API 15. Any way to know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the signature process. I had to sign the apk with the `-digestalg SHA1 -sigalg MD5withRSA` options. Strangely, even without these options I could install the apk on devices with API 19.